# addStyleSheet fails on J3.0

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm migrating some of my modules to J3.0 from J2.5 and suddenly I cannot add stylesheets to the document in J.30.
I've tried the following code with no success:

```
JHTML::stylesheet('style.css', 'modules/mod_instagallery/assets/css/');

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet('/modules/mod_instagallery/assets/css/style.css');
$document->addStyleSheet(JUri::base().'/modules/mod_instagallery/assets/css/style.css');

JHtml::stylesheet('modules/mod_instagallery/assets/css/style.css');
```

The CSS is located at **MYROOT/modules/mod_instagallery/assets/css/style.css** and the file is there in the file system. According to the page source, no css is added whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The CSS files appeared to not be loaded due to output buffering on the webserver.

Solved this by editing the php.ini file from

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

to

```
output_buffering = Off
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1

> JHtml::stylesheet() doesn't support a string as the second parameter anymore. This used to be the path to the file in Joomla 1.5 and has been removed now.

So the first one will fail due to this.
The others still work.